# Sequence of shifts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-wrangling

I am working with python and pandas with the following table/dataframe, containing information about work shifts. The cycle type defines the working/non-working days (e.g., 5-3 means 5 days working, 3 not working). The cycle day indicates in which day of the cycle the worker is (for a 5-3 cycle, this will go from 1 to 5). Finally, the shift indicates whether the worker has been in a morning (M), afternoon (A) or night (N) shift:

| Worker | Cycle_type | Cycle_day | Shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 5-3 | 1 | M |
| Alice | 5-3 | 2 | M |
| Alice | 5-3 | 3 | A |
| Alice | 5-3 | 4 | A |
| Alice | 5-3 | 5 | N |
| Bob | 6-2 | 1 | N |
| Bob | 6-2 | 2 | M |
| Bob | 6-2 | 3 | M |
| Bob | 6-2 | 4 | N |
| Bob | 6-2 | 5 | A |
| Bob | 6-2 | 6 | M |

The idea is to obtain a new column which indicates the sequence of shifts up the moment of the row. For example, Alice works 2 mornings, then 2 afternoons and then one night, so the sequence the last day would be "M1,M2,A1,A2,N1", where the numbers indicate the numer of iterations of each shift. In the case of Bob, the full sequence for the last day would be "N1,M1,M2,N2,A1,M3". The desired table would be te following:

| Worker | Cycle_type | Cycle_day | Shift | Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 5-3 | 1 | M | M1 |
| Alice | 5-3 | 2 | M | M1,M2 |
| Alice | 5-3 | 3 | A | M1,M2,A1 |
| Alice | 5-3 | 4 | A | M1,M2,A1,A2 |
| Alice | 5-3 | 5 | N | M1,M2,A1,A2,N1 |
| Bob | 6-2 | 1 | N | N1 |
| Bob | 6-2 | 2 | M | N1,M1 |
| Bob | 6-2 | 3 | M | N1,M1,M2 |
| Bob | 6-2 | 4 | N | N1,M1,M2,N2 |
| Bob | 6-2 | 5 | A | N1,M1,M2,N2,A1 |
| Bob | 6-2 | 6 | M | N1,M1,M2,N2,A1,M3 |

This sequence must be computed for each day, not knowing about the future, this is, the third day of Alice has a sequence "M1,M2,A1", as it doesn't know about the fourth and fifth day yet. I am unable to think of a way, using python and pandas, to capture all these details. Any ideas?

EDIT: It would also be nice to have the full sequence as a new column, "Full_sequence", where it is shown regardless of the day, if possible

Comment: can Alice appear after Bob, if so then Cycle_type will be 5-3?

Comment: Sorry @inquirer I'm not sure I understand. in this example Alice and Bob appear like that, but they may be in a different order. In fact, there will also be a "Date" column to know in which date are we in every row

Comment: Based on your dataframe example, rows with Alice come first, then Bob. Can further lines with Alice appear again after Bob?

Comment: @inquirer yes, indeed, and they will. This example is a snippet of a single shift cycle, but after this one they will come many more, probably different between them

Comment: and Cycle_type will be the same? It's just that unique strings are needed to avoid the loop. If there are none, then this must be done through a loop, and this will be slow if there are many lines.

Comment: Is the question no longer relevant?

Comment: Cycle_type may vary from cycle to cycle, depending on the sequence of days. This is a complex problem due to the richness of possibilities...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an older question, so the answer might be moot.

Unfortunately `GroupBy.cumsum` (as well as `GroupBy.transform("cumsum")`)  doesn't like strings (and lists), so one way to approach this would be to use [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) from `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import accumulate

def cumjoin(ser): return accumulate(ser, lambda acc, s: f"{acc},{s}")

cycle = df.groupby("Worker")["Cycle_day"].diff().fillna(-1.0).lt(0.0).cumsum()
df["Sequence"] = (
    (df["Shift"] + (df.groupby([cycle, "Shift"]).cumcount() + 1).astype("str"))
    .groupby(cycle).transform(cumjoin)
)
df["Full_sequence"] = df["Sequence"].groupby(cycle).transform("last")
```

Result (`df` your dataframe):

```
   Worker Cycle_type  Cycle_day Shift           Sequence      Full_sequence
0   Alice        5-3          1     M                 M1     M1,M2,A1,A2,N1
1   Alice        5-3          2     M              M1,M2     M1,M2,A1,A2,N1
2   Alice        5-3          3     A           M1,M2,A1     M1,M2,A1,A2,N1
3   Alice        5-3          4     A        M1,M2,A1,A2     M1,M2,A1,A2,N1
4   Alice        5-3          5     N     M1,M2,A1,A2,N1     M1,M2,A1,A2,N1
5     Bob        6-2          1     N                 N1  N1,M1,M2,N2,A1,M3
6     Bob        6-2          2     M              N1,M1  N1,M1,M2,N2,A1,M3
7     Bob        6-2          3     M           N1,M1,M2  N1,M1,M2,N2,A1,M3
8     Bob        6-2          4     N        N1,M1,M2,N2  N1,M1,M2,N2,A1,M3
9     Bob        6-2          5     A     N1,M1,M2,N2,A1  N1,M1,M2,N2,A1,M3
10    Bob        6-2          6     M  N1,M1,M2,N2,A1,M3  N1,M1,M2,N2,A1,M3
```

There's a way to avoid `accumulate`, but it is a bit convoluted:

```py
cycle = df.groupby("Worker")["Cycle_day"].diff().fillna(-1.0).lt(0.0).cumsum()
seq = df["Shift"] + (df.groupby([cycle, "Shift"]).cumcount() + 1).astype("str")

grouper = seq.groupby(cycle)
idx, idx_count = seq.index, grouper.transform("size") - grouper.cumcount()
seq_df = pd.DataFrame({"Sequence": seq, "Cycle": cycle}).loc[idx.repeat(idx_count), :]

grouper = seq_df.groupby(["Cycle", "Sequence"])
groups = grouper.transform("size") - grouper.cumcount()
df["Sequence"] = (
    seq_df.groupby(["Cycle", groups], sort=False).agg({"Sequence": ",".join})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Comment: Good solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

First Add a column into the Data frame and Just Update the data frame column order.

```
# Declare a list that is to be converted into a column
Sequence = [value of Sequence columns]
  
# Using 'Sequence' as the column name
# and equating it to the list
df['Sequence'] = Sequence

df = df[['Worker','Cycle_type','Cycle_day','Schedule','Sequence']]
```

Comment: Hi @jainam shah, thanks for the answer; however, the idea is to do make pandas compute it automatically, this is, to detect the shifts and assign "1", "2" or whatever, and make the sequence without explicitely defining them before

Comment: Hello, @datadatadata above solution work for you then.. up vote it and accept the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid not. If I understand correctly, your solution is the following: 

```
Sequence = ["M1", "M1,M2", "M1,M2,A1"...]
```

But I need pandas to automatically compute those values, as the data I am working with has thousands of rows, from hundreds of workers and possibilities